# Drupal jQuery noConflict - working for alert by not css change

Tags: drupal, jquery

Im using the jQuery noConflict method here: 
http://drupal.org/node/1058168

Now, both of the following work:

```
$jq("document").ready(function(){
    alert('alert');
});

$("document").ready(function(){
    alert('alert');
});
```

However this does work:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".view-product-slideshow .pager-num-1 img").css("display","none");
});
```

But this does not:

```
$jq("document").ready(function(){
    $jq(".view-product-slideshow .pager-num-1 img").css("display","none");
});
```

Ive used the noConflict method once before and it worked fine. Ive no idea why it would work for the alert but not the CSS change.

My site is here:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp4/shop/baby-essentials/sleepsuit-plush

Thanks

UPDATE - Ive now removed the extra code from script.js so all thats there is:

```
//Hide thumnail on product page thats being used as main image 
$jq("document").ready(function(){
    $jq(".view-product-slideshow .pager-num-1 img").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: I think its better to use hide(0) and show(0). maybe it will also fix your problem

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky changing it (on my local computer) hasn't fixed it. Your probably right about it being a better solution but its not causing this problem so ill think about it when ive sorted this bug. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is on line 61 of ur `script.js`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #
>   has no method 'smoothDivScroll'

also in that file u should have **everything** wrapped in the `.ready()` not every individual thing

Comment: Thanks for finding that @Neal but unfortunately it hasn't fixed the issue. Ive now removed everything from script.js except the css change. Thanks

Comment: Yes, me too. But I have changed the extra js that you suggested might have been causing the problem. Thanks http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp4/sites/all/themes/localhost_petitpim/script.js

Comment: ?? no but that error could be the things that is STOPPING all ur code from running

Comment: Right, thats why ive removed the other code for the example. Ive updated my main question, and if you click this link you can see ive removed everything thats relevant to this particular task. Thanks http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp4/sites/all/themes/localhost_petitpim/script.js

Comment: FOR THE 3rd TIME.   thats just code, where is that executing so i can see ur error

Comment: Ah, sorry. What do you mean by where is it executing? Under 'click to zoom' there are 3 thumbnails, the first of which should be hidden by the code. The error is that nothing happens, but when I remove the jq it works fine. I hope Ive answered your questions. Thanks

Comment: im done helping. good luck. there is NOTHING rong with ur code

Comment: OK, wish I knew why its not working. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: put it seprately and run it. ull see there is nothing rong

Comment: I know that it should work. Its quite hard to find the bug with Drupal as it creates quite a lot of markup. Its probably obvious im a bit of a newbie but it seems very strange to me that the alert would work fine with the jq but the css change wont. Does that offer any hint to what the problem might be? Thanks

Comment: i already told u. that one error on the page could be stopping everything

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the element I was trying to target with jQuery was itself generated by javascript. Changing my document.ready to window.load fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

When using the noconflict mode of jQuery, you should use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".view-product-slideshow .pager-num-1 img").css("display","none");
});
```

`jQuery` is the new `$` and you can pass jQuery as `$` to your `function()`.

Also, it's `document` and not `"document"`